# Show that any linear function from $\mathbb{K}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{K}^{m}$ is Lipschitz continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

I'm doing *Problem III.1.12* in textbook **Analysis I** by Amann.

> [image]

Could you please verify if my proof look fine or contains logical gaps/errors? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

**My attempt:**

Here $\mathbb K$ denotes $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. We endow $\mathbb K^n$ with the maximum norm $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ and $\mathbb K^m$ with an arbitrary norm $\| \cdot \|$.

Let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb K^n$ and $A = \max_{1 \le i\le n} \|f(e_i)\|$.

For all $x = \{x_1,\ldots,x_n\},y = \{y_1,\ldots,y_n\} \in \mathbb K^n$, we have $$\begin{aligned}\| f(x)-f(y) \| &= \| f(x-y) \| &&= \left\| f\left(\sum (x_i-y_i) e_i\right) \right\| \\ &= \left\| \sum (x_i-y_i) f(e_i) \right\| && \le \sum \left\|  (x_i-y_i) f(e_i) \right\| \\ &= \sum |x_i-y_i| \left\|f(e_i) \right\| && \le A\sum |x_i-y_i| \\& \le An \max_{1 \le i\le n} |x_i-y_i| &&=An \| x-y \|_\infty \end{aligned}$$

To sum up, $\| f(x)-f(y) \| \le An \| x-y\|_\infty$. Hence $f$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: Your proof uses the fact that any two norms on a finite dimensional normed linear space is equivalent. It seems correct to me. But more generally any continuous linear map between two normed linear spaces is Lipschitz. And any linear map between two finite dimensional spaces is continuous.

Comment: Looks good to me, ***endorsed, +1***.  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your verification :)))))